# Como pegar uma página de outro site usando PHP

Tags: php

Olá, estou tentando pegar os preços de uma página no site do iFood usando PHP para que, caso meu cliente altere os preços que ele colocou na página deles, o site já fazer a correção automática. O problema é que nada que eu tente funciona. Estou usando o `file_get_contents()` e mesmo assim não carrega. Ex:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://www.ifood.com.br/delivery/belo-horizonte-mg/puro-sabor-salgados---carlos-prates-carlos-prates');
print_r($contents);
```

Alguém sabe de alguma forma que eu possa capturar essa página? só preciso puxar o conteúdo dela para uma variável que o resto eu faço o tratamento...

Comment: O `file_get_contents` deveria funcionar. Não retorna nada, algum erro ou aviso?

Comment: Seu código esta retornando o HTML todo da página.

Comment: Não está retornando a página

Comment: Melhor é fazer o inverso, atualizar no seu cliente e seu site injetar a informação no iFood. Por coincidência tou com 3 clientes saindo atualmente do iFood pra um sistema próprio justamente pq o iFood ignorou uma proposta que eu tinha de API (responderam com um email enlatado, resolvi descartar eles e fazer um sistema próprio, afinal eu nem acho o produto deles tão bom assim) - E pra melhorar, com sistema próprio os clientes lucram mais nas vendas, sem ter que pagar o iFood. Jajá deleto esse comment aqui.

Comment: Outra coisa, pra esse tipo de aplicação geralmente usar a lib `curl` é mais eficiente, pois todo o gerenciamento de get, post, cookies etc está meio que pronto pra usar. Geralmente o PHP vem com `curl` instalado.

Answer (score -1):

Estive olhando o site do Ifood. O que acontece é que o site detecta qual navegador está requisitando a página antes de enviar o conteúdo. Quando ele identifica que é o PHP, ele retorna um erro.

Tentei burlar o processo com um Stream mas também não funcionou.

```
<?php

// configura o stream e as opções de Headers(cabeçalhos)
$stream = stream_context_create(
Array("http" => Array("method"  => "GET", 
  "timeout" => 30, 
  "header"  => "User-agent:".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
  "Accept"=> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding"=> " gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language"=> " pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
"Cache-Control"=> " max-age=0",
"Connection"=> " keep-alive",
"Host"=> " www.ifood.com.br",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"=> 1
                                ))); 


if ( $arquivo = fopen("https://www.ifood.com.br/delivery/belo-horizonte-mg/puro-sabor-salgados---carlos-prates-carlos-prates", 'r', false, $stream) ) { 
} 

while(!feof($arquivo))
  {
   //Mostra uma linha do arquivo
   $linha = fgets($arquivo);
   echo $linha;
  }?>
```

Comment: Hmmm suspeitei que poderia ser algo assim...

Comment: Está errada essa resposta, o problema é outro. Para entender melhor basta navegar no site com as ferramentas de desenvolvedor abertas, e olhar a aba "rede". Aí você vai conseguir ver como o site monta a página e simular exatamente os mesmos passos.